i have 2 states products and productdetail but the products state is not shown
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import {thunk} from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import { 
productDetailsReducer,
productsReducer,
} from "./reducers/productReducer";

const reducer = combineReducers({
    products: productsReducer,
    productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
});

let initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;

Screenshot:

